# Upload files with ajax? (PHP)

Tags: php, ajax

So I'm making a small script for myself, where I can upload files to my server. It works pretty well now, but whenever I try to upload bigger files it just crashes. So I think what if I'll add ajax support to make it: 1. Work better; 2. Look better.

So, this is what I have so far:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>File Uploader v1.0</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>
<a href="index.php"><img src="img/logo.png"></a>
</head>
<body>
  <center>
    <table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
      <tr>
         <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <td>
           <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
             <tr>
                <b>Please choose a file:</b><br/>
                <input type="file" name="fileup"/><br/>
                <br/>
                <input type="submit" name='submit' value="Upload"/>
             </tr>
        </form>
     </table>
</body>
</html>

<?php
    $uploadpath = 'upload/';        // directory to store the uploaded files
    $max_size = 103000000;          // maximum file size, in KiloBytes
    $allowtype = array('bmp', 'gif', 'jpg', 'jpe', 'png', 'rar', 'zip', 'exe', 'psd');        // allowed extensions

    if ( isset( $_FILES['fileup'] ) && strlen( $_FILES['fileup']['name'] ) > 1 ) {
       $uploadpath = $uploadpath . basename( $_FILES['fileup']['name'] );               // gets the file name
       $sepext = explode('.', strtolower( $_FILES['fileup']['name'] ) );
       $type = end($sepext);       // gets extension
       list ( $width, $height ) = getimagesize( $_FILES['fileup']['tmp_name'] );       // gets image width and height
       $err = '';         // to store the errors

       // Checks if the file has allowed type, size, width and height (for images)

       if ( !in_array($type, $allowtype)) $err .= 'The file: <b>'. $_FILES['fileup']['name']. '</b> not has the allowed extension type.';
       if ( $_FILES['fileup']['size'] > $max_size*1000) $err .= '<br/>Maximum file size must be: '. $max_size. ' KB.';

       // If no errors, upload the image, else, output the errors

       if ( $err == '' ) {
          $i = 1;
          while ( file_exists( $uploadpath ) ) {
              //get filename without suffix
              $rootname = basename( $_FILES['fileup']['name'], $type );
              $uploadpath = "upload/" . $rootname . "-$i." . $type;
              $i++;
          }
          if ( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['fileup']['tmp_name'], $uploadpath ) ) {
              echo '<font color="green"><b>Success!</b></font>';    
              echo '<br/>File: <b>'. basename( $_FILES['fileup']['name']). '</b>';
              echo '<br/>File type: <b>'. $_FILES['fileup']['type'] .'</b>';
              echo '<br />Size: <b>'. number_format($_FILES['fileup']['size']/1024, 3, '.', '') .'</b> KB';
              echo '<br/><br/>File path: <input type="text" value="http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), '\\/').'/'.$uploadpath.'" readonly>';
          } else echo '<b>Unable to upload the file.</b>';
       } else echo $err;
    }
?>
</center>
```

So that would be great if any of you will help me. Thank you! :)

Comment: You realize AJAX is initiated by JavaScript right? You're missing a language in the middle. Anyway; what you need to do is have a hidden iframe and point the form to that iframe (`target='iframeName'`). From there, you submit the form normally and use JavaScript to track a change in the content of the iframe, which will house the response of your upload script.

Comment: How big of a file crashes it? and a `crash` implies?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Hmmm when it's like 30+ mb. Why?

Comment: @MartyWallace Can you please assist me with more information about that? To be honest I never worked with javascript before :o

Comment: Maybe then its taking too much time to upload the file and your script hasn't crashed yet?

Comment: Eh? It just keeps uploading it for a few minutes and then just refreshes a page. No results, no nothing. @Hanky웃Panky

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky i faced crash problem, when i was experimenting to upload around 1GB file, i used `set_time_limit(0);`.

Comment: @berdyev take a look on this link http://webomnizz.com/blog/jquery/ajax-based-instant-image-upload/ to upload image without refreshing. You can modify it according to your need.

Comment: I tried to add this function into my code and it didn't work. @jogesh_pi

Comment: I will see what I can do, thank you very much! :) @jogesh_pi

Answer (score 3):

If you think that while using the ajax/javascript script would not crash then you are wrong. The problem is not the working of the code. Problem is the Maximum uploading size handled by PHP.

You need to set the value of upload_max_filesize and post_max_size in your php.ini :

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 40M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 40M
```

If you don't have the access to php.ini then ask the service provider to increase the size of uploading. You cannot change these values at run-time; uploads of file larger than the value specified in php.ini will have failed by the time execution reaches your call to ini_set.

See the [Description of core php.ini directives](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php).

Comment: okay cool, I'll do that, thank you. But let's say I don't want page to refresh while uploading a file. I want to see an ajax status bar with percentage.

Comment: It is easy to do with jquery. Search web jquery file upload as you will found thousands of that